# How can i create/add an event of contextMenuStrip1 that is connected with notifyIcon?

Tags: c#, winforms

I added a notifyIcon to my designer in Form1 .
Then i hid it :

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (FormWindowState.Minimized == WindowState)
                Hide();
        }
```

Then added in the designer contextMenuStrip .
In the notifyIcon in the property ContextMenuStrip i selected the contextMenuStrip1 .

Then in the contextMenuStrip in the items edit menu i added a new item called it for the test : Close Application .

Now when i'm running my application and resize down hid the Form i see the icon in the tray icons right click on it i see the menu : Close Application

Now the problem is where/how do i create an event for the Close Application so one single click on it with the mouse left button will do something ? (Close the application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double click the "Close Application" menu item to get a stub handler inserted for you.  Now just add in the Close() method for the Form:

```
    private void closeApplicationToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

EDIT: Here's a picture just to make it clearer:

[image: Double Click to get default handler]